# Python/pyspark data frame rearrange columns

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame in python/pyspark with columns `id` `time` `city` `zip` and so on......

Now I added a new column `name` to this data frame.

Now I have to arrange the columns in such a way that the `name` column comes after `id`

I have done like below

```
change_cols = ['id', 'name']

cols = ([col for col in change_cols if col in df] 
        + [col for col in df if col not in change_cols])

df = df[cols]
```

I am getting this error

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Reference 'id' is ambiguous, could be: id#609, id#1224.;"
```

Why is this error occuring. How can I rectify this.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can use `select` to change the order of the columns:

```
df.select("id","name","time","city")
```

Comment: `df.select(["id", "name", "time", "city"])` also works.

Answer (score 40):

If you're working with a large number of columns:

```
df.select(sorted(df.columns))
```

Comment: For people that are not Python experts, `sorted` is built-in Python function, you don't have to import anything extra

Comment: On what basis does it sort? Does it sort on basis on column name

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to reorder some of them, while keeping the rest and not bothering about their order :

```
def get_cols_to_front(df, columns_to_front) :
    original = df.columns
    # Filter to present columns
    columns_to_front = [c for c in columns_to_front if c in original]
    # Keep the rest of the columns and sort it for consistency
    columns_other = list(set(original) - set(columns_to_front))
    columns_other.sort()
    # Apply the order
    df = df.select(*columns_to_front, *columns_other)

    return df
```

Comment: There is a typo, should be 'columns_other = list(set(original) - set(columns_to_front))'. Nice solution!

Comment: Corrected. Thank you for spotting :)