# Adding a new column in the first ordinal position in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a  pyspark data frame like:

```
+--------+-------+-------+
| col1   | col2  | col3  |
+--------+-------+-------+
|  25    |  01   |     2 |
|  23    |  12   |     5 | 
|  11    |  22   |     8 |
+--------+-------+-------+
```

and I want to create new dataframe by adding a new column like this:

```
+--------------+-------+-------+-------+
| new_column   | col1  | col2  | col3  |
+--------------+-------+-------+-------+
|  0           |  01   |     2 |  0    |
|  0           |  12   |     5 |  0    |
|  0           |  22   |     8 |  0    |
+--------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I know I can add column by:

```
df.withColumn("new_column", lit(0))
```

but it adds column at last like this:

```
+--------------+-------+-------+-------------+
| col1         | col1  | col2  | new_column  |
+--------------+-------+-------+-------------+
|  25          |  01   |     2 |  0          |
|  23          |  12   |     5 |  0          |
|  11          |  22   |     8 |  0          |
+--------------+-------+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: add using withColumn and  select('new_column',other columns).

Answer (score 13):

You can always reorder the columns in a spark DataFrame using `select`, as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42913947/5858851).

In this case, you can also achieve the desired output in one step using `select` and `alias` as follows:

```python
df = df.select(lit(0).alias("new_column"), "*")
```

Which is logically equivalent to the following SQL code:

```sql
SELECT 0 AS new_column, * FROM df
```

Answer (score 8):

you can reorder columns using select.

```
df = df.select('new_column','col1','col2','col3')
df.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.select(['new_column', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

Answer (score -5):

You can use the INSERT function

```
    df.insert(0, 'new_column', [data,,,])
```

thanks