# Sorting pyspark dataframe accroding to columns values

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am beginner in Spark and I am looking for a solution for my issue.
I'm trying to sort a dataframe according to the number of **null values** each column contains in ascending order.

For example:
data:

```
column1    Column2     Column3
a          d           h
b          null        null
null       e           i
null       f           h
null       null        k
c          g           l
```

After sorting, the dataframe should be:

```
Column3     Colum2     Column1
```

All I could do is to count each column's null values.

```
data.select([count(when(col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in data.columns])
```

Now, I have no idea how to continue. I wish you could help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python/pyspark data frame rearrange columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42912156/python-pyspark-data-frame-rearrange-columns)

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44627386/11301900

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution, it work as you want:

```
#Based on your code
df=df.select([count(when(col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns])

# Convert dataframe to dictionary (Python 3.x)
dict = list(map(lambda row: row.asDict(), df.collect()))[0]

# Create a dictionary with sorted values based on keys
sorted_dict={k: v for k, v in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}

# Create a sorted list with the column names
sorted_cols = [c for c in sorted_dict.keys()]

# With .select() method we re-order the dataframe
df.select(sorted_cols).show()
```

Comment: Thanks very much for replying. However, it showed an error in the dictionary line 'Unsupported class file major version 55'. I'll try to fix it. Thank you so much

Comment: @Mus are you using Python 2.x ? Because my implementation is for Python 3.x

Comment: For python 2.x take a  look in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key

Comment: If my answer is ok for you you can accepted if you want :-)

Comment: Yes I'm using Python2.7. I tried python3 and your answer works 100%. Thanks again

Comment: @Mus Perfect! :-)